How can I fix the decoding error in my gRPC Node.js application?
I'm new to gRPC with Node.js, and I'm trying to create a simple request to understand how it works.
I asked ChatGPT for a simple application where the client sends data to the server, and the server returns the same data using the Proto protocol.
I understand that Proto is typically used for server-to-server communication, but I want to use it for client-to-server communication for learning purposes.
I have this code, but it's not working. The error I get from the client is:
Success: Invalid data

And the internal error from the server is:
Error decoding data: TypeError: Data.decode is not a function
    at file:///Users/user/node-proto/server.mjs:32:23

The problem seems to be that the decode function does not exist on the Data object. I'm not sure what I should use instead.
Here is the full code for the server:
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import grpc from "@grpc/grpc-js";
import protoLoader from "@grpc/proto-loader";
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";
import cors from "cors";

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(cors());

const PROTO_PATH = path.join("./message.proto");

const packageDefinition = protoLoader.loadSync(PROTO_PATH, {
  keepCase: true,
  longs: String,
  enums: String,
  defaults: true,
  oneofs: true,
});
const protoDescriptor = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinition);
const Data = protoDescriptor.Data;

app.use(bodyParser.raw({ type: "application/x-protobuf" }));

app.post("/data", (req, res) => {
  try {
    const data = Data.decode(req.body);
    console.log(`Received data: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
    res.status(200).send("Data received");
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error decoding data:", err);
    res.status(400).send("Invalid data");
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});

message.proto:
syntax = "proto3";

message Data {
  string id = 1;
  string name = 2;
}

And here is the client code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Protobuf Client</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Send Data</h1>
    <button id="sendData">Send Data</button>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/protobufjs/6.11.2/protobuf.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      document
        .getElementById("sendData")
        .addEventListener("click", async () => {
          const protoRoot = await protobuf.load("message.proto");
          const Data = protoRoot.lookupType("Data");
          const payload = { id: "123", name: "John Doe" };
          const errMsg = Data.verify(payload);

          if (errMsg) {
            throw Error(errMsg);
          }

          const message = Data.create(payload);
          const buffer = Data.encode(message).finish();

          fetch("http://localhost:3000/data", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/x-protobuf",
            },
            body: buffer,
          })
            .then((response) => response.text())
            .then((data) => {
              console.log("Success:", data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.error("Error:", error);
            });
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix the decoding error on the server?

The @grpc/proto-loader library does not provide this direct message decoding API that you are looking for. The purpose of the @grpc/proto-loader library is to provide service types to gRPC implementations, not to provide APIs for interacting directly with messages. You should instead use Protobuf.js, which you already used in your client code.
